# check multiple values in an array against a single reference value in swift and then doing action based on the index of the matched value

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing, swift2

i'm trying to check multiple values in an array against a reference value (a count down timer).

For example :

X is a time value i want to do actions when X == timerInfo.timerCount,
same for Y

I can't figure out how to check if either value X or Y in the array [X,Y] is == my timerInfo.timerCount value, and if so take the data from that index of timerInfo!.alertInfo[X or Y] and do stuff with it

```
        if timerCounter - timerInfo!.alertInfo[0...timerInfo!.alertInfo.count-1] + 1 == timerInfo.timerCount {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)

            //update text from value
            alertInfo.text = "\(timerInfo!.alertInfo[0]!.alertText)"
            self.view.backgroundColor = timerInfo!.alertInfo[0]!.alertColor
        }
```

Comment: You could use an NSArray and use its indexOfObject mehtod. Or you iterate over the indices from 0 to count-1.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, i iterated, just checking its working and will post

Answer (score 0):

```
       for i in (0...timerInfo!.alertInfo.count-1) {
            print("\(timerCounter!), \((timerInfo!.alertInfo[i]?.alertCounter)!) , \(timerInfo!.timerCount)")
            if timerCounter! - (timerInfo!.alertInfo[i]?.alertCounter)! - 1 == (timerCounter! - timerInfo!.timerCount) {

                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
                alertInfo.text = "\(timerInfo!.alertInfo[i]!.alertText!)"
                self.view.backgroundColor = timerInfo!.alertInfo[i]!.alertColor
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.contains(3) // true
arr.contains(0) // false
```